# Swap key modifiers for individual applications in OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any way I can remap <kbd>Cmd</kbd> to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for individual applications or Windows on OSX?

I'm trying to work out a way to do this for VirtualBox as I keep using the wrong keys to copy and paste between OSX and Windows running in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Products like [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/) or [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) have this feature built in.

It seems like something Virtual Box should be able to do through it's guest additions.